# Python selenium how to keep browser open?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import time
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException




chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
search_key = '성남 스터디카페'

url = "https://map.naver.com/v5/search/" + search_key
driverPath = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
```

I am making web crawler and I can see the page that I entered, but it keeps closing after 2~3 seconds.

I also used detach option.
Chrome version is 91.0.4472.124, so I downloaded 91 version webdriver, but the browser is still closing.

Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's closing because the main python process will stop after running the code.
If you want to keep the browser is opened, simply add in the end:

```
time.sleep(1000)
```